# How to store links in DB number wise?

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

This is my code,

```
HtmlNodeCollection categorynode = null;

categorynode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='parentMenu arrow']");//"//div[@class='drop-menu']//a[@href]"
if (categorynode != null)
{
                    foreach (HtmlNode Node in categorynode)
                    {

                        string Html = Node.InnerHtml;
                        if (Html != null)
                        {

                            HtmlDocument Node2 = new HtmlDocument();
                            Node2.LoadHtml(Html);
 foreach (HtmlNode link in Node2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
                        {
                            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                            Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"(?<=[\?&]id=)\d+(?=\&|\#|$)").Match(att.Value).Value);
                            string Links = att.Value;
                            Modelclass _ms = new Modelclass();
                            _ms.link = Links;
                            _ms.Name = "Apple";
                            _ms.CID = 0;
                            _ms.Type = "Categories";
                            Controller cc = new Controller();
                            cc.InsertCategories(_ms);
                        }
                    }

}
```

I have tables in my DB were I have set an ID as a primary key but when I store all these links in DB it should be sorted but it is like 1 2 3 9 7 6 ,
is there something wrong with my code or what should i do please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep an ID in your table where you are storing your links and set ID to auto increment that will help may be